# Comparing $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ and $\nabla$ in $L^p$ space for $p \in (1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $\mathbb{T}^n := \bigl(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \bigr)^n$ be $n$-dimensional torus.

Then, I wonder if $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ and $\nabla$ are "equivalent" in $L^p(\mathbb{T}^n)$ for each $p \in (1,\infty)$.

That is, for any $f \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{T}^n)$, do we have some constants $C_1,C_2>0$ depending only on $p$ and $n$ such that
\begin{equation}
C_1\lVert (-\Delta)^{1/2} f \rVert_p \geq  \lVert \nabla f \rVert_p
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
C_2 \lVert \nabla f \rVert_p \geq  \lVert (-\Delta)^{1/2} f \rVert_p
\end{equation}

For $p=2$, I see that $\lVert (-\Delta)^{1/2} f \rVert_2=\lVert \nabla f \rVert_2$. I wonder what happens in general case, except for endpoints.

Comment: You are asking about properties of the Riesz Transform. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_transform

Comment: @HansEngler Yes, now I remember the name. Nevertheless, I cannot find in your link any information about upper / lower boundedness of the Riesz transform. Could you provide more details?